How to split variadic template arguments without additional copies?
Consider the following C++23 code:
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

struct W1
{
    int n;
    bool b;
    W1(int x, bool f) : n(x), b(f) {}
};


struct W2
{
    long n;
    W2(long x) : n(x) {}
    W2(const W2& other) : n(other.n) { std::puts("copy ctor"); }
    W2(W2&& other) : n(other.n) { std::puts("move ctor"); }
};

int main() {
    Foo<W1, W2, W2> foo{std::in_place_type<W1>, 42, true,
                        std::in_place_type<W2>, 7L,
                        std::in_place_type<W2>, 9};

    std::cout << std::tuple_size_v<decltype(foo.data)> << '\n';
    std::cout << get<0>(foo.data).n << '\n';
    std::cout << get<0>(foo.data).b << '\n';
    std::cout << get<1>(foo.data).n << '\n';
    std::cout << get<2>(foo.data).n << '\n';

    return 0;
}

Here, Foo is a class template that has an std::tuple data member data (ignoring the encapsulation for the sake of simplicity), which in this case consists of three objects: W1{42, true}, W2{7L} and W2{9}.
My question is: How to create class Foo that conforms to the usage shown above?
(note that Foo should be able to construct any number of objects of any type)
I have made it work like this:
#include <tuple>

template <typename>
inline constexpr bool is_in_place_type_v = false;

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_in_place_type_v<std::in_place_type_t<T>> = true;

template <std::size_t Offset, std::size_t... Ints>
auto make_offset_sequence_impl(std::index_sequence<Ints...>) {
    return std::index_sequence<Offset + Ints...>{};
}

template <std::size_t Offset, std::size_t N>
auto make_offset_sequence() {
    return make_offset_sequence_impl<Offset>(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

// helper type that effectively allows for splitting a tuple into two
// , based on the position of `std::in_place_type`
template <int N, typename... Types>
struct Indexer
{};

// end-case
template <int N>
struct Indexer<N>
{
    using arg_seq = decltype(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    using rest_seq = std::index_sequence<>;
    using type = Indexer;
};

template <int N, typename Type, typename... Types>
struct Indexer<N, Type, Types...>
{
    using type = Indexer<N + 1, Types...>::type;
};

template <int N, typename PT, typename... Types>
requires is_in_place_type_v<std::decay_t<PT>>
struct Indexer<N, PT, Types...>
{
    using arg_seq = decltype(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    using rest_seq = decltype(make_offset_sequence<N, sizeof...(Types) + 1>());

    using type = Indexer;
    using next = Indexer<N, Types...>::type;
};

template <typename... Types>
struct Foo
{
    std::tuple<Types...> data;

    static auto m_init() { return std::tuple{}; }

    template <typename T, typename... Ts>
    static auto m_init(const std::in_place_type_t<T>&, Ts&&... args) {

        using indices = Indexer<0, std::in_place_type_t<T>, Ts...>::next;

        auto lambda1 = [&args...]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        {
            return std::tuple{
                    T{std::get<Is>(std::tuple{std::forward<Ts>(args)...})...}
                };
        };

        auto lambda2 = [&args...]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
            return m_init(std::get<Is>(std::tuple{std::forward<Ts>(args)...})...);
        };

        return std::tuple_cat(lambda1(typename indices::arg_seq{}),
                              lambda2(typename indices::rest_seq{}));
    }

    template <typename... Ts>
    explicit Foo(Ts&&... ts) : data(m_init(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)) {}
};

However, this produces more copies/moves than a regular constructor (used like Foo foo{W1{42, true}, W2{7L}, W2{9}};) would, thus defeating the purpose of std::in_place_type. Here is a demonstration.
Does anybody know how to do this better, i.e. without invoking any copy/move constructors?

Use std::forward_as_tuple instead of std::tuple for intermediate tuples.

@Jarod42 Thanks for the hint, it is useful. However, how do I forward_as_tuple a tuple created using tuple_cat?

Why making your life miserable if this is nicely resolved, by use of aggregate initialization?  https://godbolt.org/z/v8WrMxcvv

@MarekR Because I want to construct in place. Without invoking copy/move constructors.

@lobelk where in my example you have one of that? Aggregate initialization does everything in place.

@MarekR "copy ctor" is printed out twice in your godbolt link.

You have extra copies with std::tuple usage instead of std::forward_as_tuple.
In addition, you have extra copy with "recursive" std::tuple_cat.
For the later, you might concatenate factories or types with conversion operator:
template <typename F>
struct ConversionFactory{
    operator std::invoke_result_t<F>() { return f(); }
    F f;
};

template <typename... Types>
struct Foo
{
    std::tuple<Types...> data;

    Foo(const Foo&) = default;

    static auto m_init() { return std::tuple{}; }

    template <typename T, typename... Ts>
    static auto m_init(const std::in_place_type_t<T>&, Ts&&... args) {

        using indices = Indexer<0, std::in_place_type_t<T>, Ts...>::next;

        auto lambda1 = [&args...]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        {
            return std::tuple(ConversionFactory([&](){ return T{std::get<Is>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(args)...))...}; }));
        };

        auto lambda2 = [&args...]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
            return m_init(std::get<Is>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(args)...))...);
        };

        return std::tuple_cat(lambda1(typename indices::arg_seq{}), lambda2(typename indices::rest_seq{}));
    }

    template <typename... Ts>
    explicit Foo(Ts&&... ts) : data(m_init(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)) {}

    template <typename... Ts>
    requires (std::is_same_v<Ts, Types> && ...)
    explicit Foo(Ts&&... ts) : data(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) {}
};

Demo

In your demo, you still have move constructors being invoked. That makes std::in_place_type obsolete. There should be no copying/moving involved.

Ok, this technically works, but let's be realistic, would you actually use this? Also, std::function looks like a big overkill for a goal of just constructing in place. Honestly, I would rather ditch the in place construction and force the client to pay for the copy, than do this. Call me religious, but I believe this is not the best that C++ can do.

std::function can be replaced to store lambda directly, require to move the class outside though.

Could you please show it in code?

Demo

Very interesting and useful trick indeed, thank you for teaching me! You copy a trivial factory function instead of the object. GCC optimizes it away completely. I still keep wondering though, is there a simpler way. Maybe one that looks very different from the code I have initially suggested... I will leave it for a few days and then, if nothing else comes up, I will mark this as the answer. Thank you again.

If std::tuple supports std::piecewise_construct (as std::pair) you might have indeed clearer interface. I didn't look closely to indexer code, but it is a candidate of simplification too.

Hmm, std::piecewise_construct, that is interesting. Because, actually, I am not using std::tuple exactly, but a custom tuple implementation that I might be able to change and add support for std::piecewise_construct. I will look into it, thanks again.

Could you please simplify your answer by removing the first two pieces of code since they aren't really the solution. It would be much easier to follow for people who stumble on this post. I would mark it as accepted answer than. Also, it would be good if you mention std::piecewise_construct in the answer since you mentioning that in the comment led me to resolving my issue in the end. Also, thanks again for helping me out!
